# passing a method/property name as a parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it's possible to pass a method/property as a parameter in JavaScript.

An example of this would be something like this:

```js
function uniq(list, property) {
        var flags = [], output = [], l = list.length, i;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (flags[list[i].property]) continue;
            flags[list[i].property] = true;
            output.push(list[i].property);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Is it possible to do such a thing? I'm in the process of trying to read through a single list of objects but have quite a few methods that will read through this list, just with very similar methods so I wish to eliminate a bit of redundancy.

I've tried passing the property name as a string but obviously that has thrown back an error.

Comment: You mean to want to call a method or access a property using the string value of a variable? use the `[]` notation. `var x = 'prop'; y[x] = 10;`

Comment: where is `a` coming from?

Comment: Using a string was just a guess I took at trying to pass the property name which didn't work. I don't really mind what type it is, as long as I can pass it as a parameter and point it to the specific item in each object

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry Nina, I edited to make it a bit more readable. First time poster on here...

Comment: this `list[i].property` should be this `list[i][property]`. now should work you function.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you, that worked. I've struggling to find an answer for this all day.